# Order of operations when creating new object with .Select()

Tags: c#, linq

When stepping through the code below I can see an instance of OtherThing being created prior to setting the IsActive property.  However when enumerating the collection a second time IsActive is not set.  Why is this true?

```
public interface IISActive
{
    bool IsActive { get; set; }
}

public class Thing : IISActive
{
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}


public class OtherThing : IISActive
{
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public OtherThing(IISActive arg)
    {
        IsActive = arg.IsActive;
    }
}



class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        IEnumerable<IISActive> list = GetThings().Select(x => new OtherThing(x));  // .ToList() fixes it

        foreach (IISActive t in list.Skip(1))  // object constructed here
            t.IsActive = true;


        foreach (IISActive t in list)
            Console.WriteLine(t.IsActive.ToString());

        // Actual Output:
        // False
        // False
        // False


        // Expected Output:
        // False
        // True
        // True

        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    static IEnumerable<IISActive> GetThings()
    {
        List <Thing> list = new List<Thing>();
        list.Add(new Thing());
        list.Add(new Thing());
        list.Add(new Thing());
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: The resulting `IEnumerable<T>` is *not* a collection. When you enumerate the second time, `Select` is executed again, hence you get new objects. If you want collection, add `.ToList()` / `ToArray()` or similar after `Select`.

Comment: Thank you Ivan but I still don't understand.  Only two instances of OtherThing are created and the IsActive property is set AFTER the object is created.  So why is it printing False?

Comment: Because as I mentioned, the objects you print are not the objects you set that property. The objects you set the property are gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's caused by deffered execution in LINQ. Query is not executed on this line:

```
IEnumerable<IISActive> list = GetThings().Select(x => new OtherThing(x));
```

But when you enumerate your `IEnumerable`. The problem is, `Select` is executed every time you enumerate, so actually those two foreach created five objects of `OtherThing` (two in first enumeration, and three more in second one).

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate over existing collections, but that’s not what you’re doing.

`Select` returns an enumerable which *will not execute* until you enumerate it - like using `foreach` or `ToList`. Moreover, it does not cache results, so when you enumerate it again, it runs the full enumeration logic again.
 - including the selector portion.

You’re enumerating twice, and therefore your `Select` selector is being run *twice* for every `Thing`. Once at the first enumeration, and once at the second.

When you use `ToList`, you are enumerating the source and appending each item *to a list* which is then returned. Since you then use the list instead of the enumerator returned by `Select`, the `Select` selector is only run once per object *at the point you call* `ToList`.